# Python automail triggering 2 times for 1st time then after triggering single time

Tags: python

I have a python script for auto mail to multiple plants, the script initially (1st attempt) triggering 2 time for each plant, if again I run the script it will triggers as per the requirement one time only.
please help how to prevent from triggering 2 times.

my code as below

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd  
import win32com.client as win32  
from pretty_html_table import build_table

EXCEL_FILE_PATH = Path.cwd() / "D:\\TestPython\\Bulkautomailtest.xlsx"
ATTACHMENT_DIR = Path.cwd() / "Attachments"
ATTACHMENT_DIR.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

data = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE_PATH, sheet_name="QC_Rel_Tracker")

column_name = "PlantCode"
unique_values = data\[column_name\].unique()

for unique_value in unique_values:
data_output = data.query(f"{column_name} == @unique_value")
output_path = ATTACHMENT_DIR / f"{unique_value}.xlsx"
data_output.to_excel(output_path, index=False)

email_list = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE_PATH, sheet_name="MailID")

outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")
for index, row in email_list.iterrows():
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = row\["To"\]
mail.CC = row\["CC"\]
mail.Subject = f"Financial Report for: {row\['PlantCode'\]}"
attachment_path = str(ATTACHMENT_DIR / f"{row\['PlantCode'\]}.xlsx")
ht = pd.read_excel(attachment_path)
htm = ht.to_html()
Ptable = build_table(ht, 'green_light',font_size='small',font_family='calibri',border_bottom_color='black',width='max',text_align='left',)
mail.HTMLBody = f"""
<b>Hi {row\['PlantCode'\]}</b>,<br><br>
Please find attached the report for """ + htm +""".<br><br>
Best Regards,<br>
"""

    mail.Display()
    
    # mail.Send()
```

I'm expecting to trigger one time when the code runs

Comment: The indentation seems to be incorrect. The loop should be indented. Can you fix the indentation?

Comment: Indentation is in line, in post it's not properly aligned

Comment: It would be best to condense this down into a minimal example that does just the bare-bones of what you need and then rephrase your question around that. As it stands, this is a little to specific.